# How to set an automatic pause at the entrypoint of an app in container for remote debugging?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I'm doing remote debugging in container. I have msvsmon.exe installed and running in container and I know how to attach the running process in Visual Studio. However, my entry app executes and exits very fast before I can attach it to local VS. Is there a method to set an automatic pause in the Main method of the app to give me time to attach it? I don't want to set sleep because I don't want that to appear in production. My app is C# app and I'm using VS2017. Any hints are very welcome and will be helpful.

Comment: You should debug on a *separate* instance from the production instance. Duplicate the instance and debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have usually use this entrypoint in my containers

```
  entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 2073600"]
```

is just a sheebang with a command sleep, of course the milliseconds included.

Your welcome

Comment: I found that won't pause while executing the code at the first line in Main[], it will pause before I run the executable right?

Comment: entrypoint = when container start, your code should be already built, except your are concatenating multiple command in your entrypoint . if your app is running on a CMD or command in docker compose, nothing to worry about